# Valence electrons in DNA nucleotide addition

Tags: biochemistry

Can anyone explain the movement of valence electrons during the nucleophilic attack that occurs during DNA synthesis? The 3' oxygen starts with two lone pairs of electrons but what happens during the formation of the phosphodiester bond?